# Linux GPSD is more accurate than the raw data from GPS mouse

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, gps, gpsd

I bought a cheap USB GPS mouse and want to read the location information using a Raspberry Pi. The raw (serial) data from the GPS mouse looks like this:

```
$GPRMC,130312.00,A,4751.29758,N,01208.72343,E,0.067,,140721,,,A*7E 
$GPVTG,,T,,M,0.067,N,0.125,K,A*24 
$GPGGA,130312.00,4751.29758,N,01208.72343,E,1,08,1.46,450.1,M,45.7,M,,*5F 
$GPGSA,A,3,08,21,27,32,22,01,10,03,,,,,2.79,1.46,2.37*07 
$GPGSV,3,1,10,01,41,288,36,03,17,228,21,08,66,190,24,1
0,31,054,08*7B 
$GPGSV,3,2,10,14,17,316,13,21,66,300,37,22,41,231,29,24,00,026,*74 
$GPGSV,3,3,10,27,38,157,17,32,41,096,27*7D 
$GPGLL,4751.29758,N,01208.72343,E,130312.00,A,A*67
```

It uses the NMEA protocol, which is documented here: https://www.ifm.com/download/files/nmea_protocol_cr3102/$file/nmea_protocol_cr3102.pdf

So for example after $GPLL in the last line there is the latitude and the longitude in degrees, minutes and seconds. So from this data we can read:
`lat: 47°51'29.758''`
`lon: 12°08'7.2343''`

These values can easily be converted to decimal degrees by adding the minutes divided by 60 to the degrees and adding the seconds divided by 60*60 to that result. So the decimal coordinates are:
`lat: 47.8582661111°`
`lon: 12.1353428611°`

There is a well known package for linux called GPSD. Is has some demo programs to display the data visually. If I run `CGPS -s` in a terminal window I get the following data:
`lat: 47.85485133°`
`lon: 12.14536133°`

The problem is that both the results differ a lot and tests have shown that the data from `CGPS -s` is more accurate. But how is that possible? I am reading the raw data and having worse results than a package which can also only read the raw data. Neither of the results is very accurate, but the data from `CGPS -s` is way more accurate.

Does someone know why that is and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: What is a "GPS mouse"?  Is it an ordinary computer mouse, with a built-in GPS receiver?  What a... curious concept.

Comment: @SteveSummit: A [“GPS mouse”](https://de.zxc.wiki/wiki/Maus_(GNSS)) is a receiver for GPS data. It is not a [“computer mouse”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse). They are so-named because of their visual similarity to a [biological mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse). Neither is actually a biological mouse.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Huh.  I work with GPS receivers almost every day, and somehow I had never heard that term.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interpreting the NMEA data incorrectly.  NMEA uses degrees plus decimal minutes, *not* degrees/minutes/seconds.
When you see

```
$GPGGA,130312.00,4751.29758,N,01208.72343,E
```

that's actually 47 degrees, 51.29758 minutes north latitude and 12 degrees, 8.72343 minutes east longitude.  Converted to decimal degrees it's 47.854959,12.145390, more or less as `cgps` said.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you very much!